# Git Remote Push Deploy Workflow on Windows

Tags: git, github

I am trying to follow this guide on windows for remote push to deploy on windows server.

https://ma.ttias.be/simple-git-push-workflow-deploy-code-server/

1. cloned repo from git server on my laptop
2. added a remote location to my server.

   `$ git remote add live \\\\hostname\\E\\myapp\\.git`

git config looks like this:

```
[remote "live"]
    url = \\\\hostname\\E\\myapp\\.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/live/*
```

3. created a bare repo on the app server. Using git bash

```
    cd \e
    mkdir myapp
    mkdir .git
    cd .git
    git init --bare
    git clone /e/.git /e/myapp
```

4. added post-receive in e:\myapp.git\hooks folder

```
    #!/bin/sh
    git --work-tree=E:\\myapp --git-dir=E:\\myapp\\.git checkout -f
    git --work-tree=E:\\myapp --git-dir=E:\\myapp\\.git pull
    echo "Hooray, the new version is published!"
    exit 0
```

Test 1: git push live master

```
Enumerating objects: 201, done.
Counting objects: 100% (201/201), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (198/198), done.
Writing objects: 100% (201/201), 86.90 KiB | 7.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 201 (delta 117), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (117/117), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote:
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: other way.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

I ran the following command

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

Test 2:

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 281 bytes | 281.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To \\patlbearing02\E\bot-live\.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Working directory has staged changes)
```

I am stuck at this now, not sure what is wrong. I am new to git, I tried lot of searching but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, with the help of my friend.

**Server Side Changes**

**Mistake 1.**

One big mistake I was doing is, my understanding of the clone was wrong. Clone does clone the repo and keeps the connection. I had to use the main repo as remote not the cloned repo, as I did above. I had to change to code for clone (didnt have to but having .git on root was bad choice I was going to delete that thinking it was of no use after getting copied to myapp but I was wrong) and also for adding remote on my laptop.

I deleted myapp and .git on server. And I changed Step 3. As below

Old:

```
    cd \e
    mkdir myapp
    mkdir .git
    cd .git
    git init --bare
    git clone /e/.git /e/myapp
```

New:

```
cd \e
mkdir myapp
mkdir myapp.git
cd myapp.git
git init --bare
git clone /e/myapp.git /e/myapp
```

**Mistake 2.**

post-receive hook needed complete UNC, it runs remotely but doesn't identify local paths. I am not sure why, maybe windows specific. Love to know answer from experts.

so I changed no 4 to

Old:

```
  #!/bin/sh
    git --work-tree=E:\\myapp --git-dir=E:\\myapp\\.git checkout -f
    git --work-tree=E:\\myapp --git-dir=E:\\myapp\\.git pull
    echo "Hooray, the new version is published!"
    exit 0
```

New:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    git --work-tree=\\\\hostname\\e\\myapp --git-dir=\\\\hostname\\e\\myapp.git checkout -f   #notice I am pointing to myapp.git not myapp\\.git (it is there but its cloned we need to use main bare repo here)
    git --work-tree=\\\\hostname\\e\\myapp --git-dir=\\\\hostname\\e\\myapp.git pull
    echo "Hooray, the new version is published!"
    exit 0
```

**On Laptop/Development Machine Side:**

I was adding cloned git repo, instead, I should have used the main repo.

Old

```
$ git remote add live \\\\hostname\\E\\myapp\\.git
```

New:

```
$ git remote add live \\\\hostname\\E\\myapp.git  #notice I am pointing to myapp.git not myapp\\.git (it is there but its cloned we need to use main bare repo here)
```

Test: git push live master

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 280 bytes | 93.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking connectivity: 3, done.
remote: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
remote: Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
remote: See git-pull(1) for details.
remote:
remote:     git pull <remote> <branch>
remote:
remote: If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
remote:
remote:     git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master
remote:
remote: Hooray, the new version is published!
To \\hostname\E\myapp.git
   1460906..1ec756d  master -> master
```